# Execute powershell script remotely on Amazon EC2 instance from my local computer

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an Amazon EC2 instance.

Using powershell on my local workstation, I want to be able to remote into my Amazon EC2 instance and execute some commands.

I have found many articles online but none are working or I misunderstood them (probably the latter).

Some I tried are
[Managing Windows EC2 Instances remotely with Powershell](https://blogs.iis.net/thomad/archive/2010/08/12/managing-windows-amazon-ec2-machines-remotely-with-powershell.aspx)
[Administering EC2 instance with Windows Powershell](https://serverfault.com/questions/191723/administering-ec2-instance-with-windows-powershell)
[Enabling- PSRemoting](http://powershell.com/cs/forums/t/9879.aspx)
[How to Run PowerShell Commands on Remote Computers](http://www.howtogeek.com/117192/how-to-run-powershell-commands-on-remote-computers/)

My understanding is that I need to:

```
Amazon EC2 Dashboard > Network & Security > Security Groups > Add port 5985

//Local & EC2 PowerShell(Administrator)
enable-psremoting -force

//Local PowerShell(Administrator)
set-item wsman:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -value "*" -force

$password = convertto-securestring -asplaintext -force -string myPassword
$credential = new-object -typename system.management.automation.pscredential -argumentlist "myUsername", $password
$session = new-pssession ec2-00-00-00-000.compute-1.amazonaws.com -credential $credential
enter-pssession $session
```

But I get this error

```
new-pssession : [ec2-00-00-00-000.compute-1.amazonaws.com] Connecting to remote server
ec2-00-00-00-000.compute-1.amazonaws.com failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot complete the
operation. Verify that the specified computer name is valid, that the computer is accessible over the network, and
that a firewall exception for the WinRM service is enabled and allows access from this computer. By default, the WinRM
firewall exception for public profiles limits access to remote computers within the same local subnet. For more
information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
At line:1 char:12
+ $session = new-pssession ec2-00-00-00-000.compute-1.amazonaws.com -credential $c ...
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.Manageme....RemoteRunspace:RemoteRunspace) [New-PSSession], PSRemotin
   gTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WinRMOperationTimeout,PSSessionOpenFailed
```

Comment: Are you allowing ports 5985/5986 locally? Run through `winrm quickconfig` to confirm that both machines are configured correctly (though I think enable-psremoting should have handled this step).

Comment: @HyperAnthony I ran `winrm quickconfig` -> I got `WinRM service is already running on this machine. WinRM is already set up for remote management on this computer.`

Comment: What OS is your Amazon server?

Comment: @MDMoore313 Windows Server 2012 Standard

Comment: @That-_-Guy__ Have you tried using `-Credential get-credential` instead of supplying them in variables? Just to eliminate that as a possible problem?

Comment: @That-_-Guy__ What's configured in Windows as the host name, and can you ping that? Does it have a internet routable IP?

Comment: @MDMoore313 i used get-credential, still no luck when I entered my password in the popup. Hostname is `WIN-BLAHBLAH` I can ping the public IP and public DNS `ec2-00-00-00-000.compute-1.amazonaws.com` successfully

Comment: @That-_-Guy__ have you restarted the server after doing `winrm quickconfig`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Solution found [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=424315&#424315).

The missing link was to (on the EC2 instance) open *Windows Firewall with Advanced Security* and edit an inbound rule.

Full Steps:

**EC2 Instance**
1) Open *PowerShell* as administrator
2) Enter `enable-psremoting -force`
3) Open *Windows Firewall with Advanced Security*
4) *Inbound Rules* -> Find *Windows Remote Management (Http-In)* - there are 2, do this for both
5) *Right click* -> *Properties* -> *Advanced* -> Check *public*

**Local**
6) Open *PowerShell* as administrator
7) Enter `enable-psremoting -force`
8) Enter the following:

```
$password = convertto-securestring -asplaintext -force -string MY_PASSWORD  
$credential = new-object -typename system.management.automation.pscredential -argumentlist "MY_USERNAME", $password  
$session = new-pssession MY_EC2_PUBLIC_IP -credential $credential  
enter-pssession $session  
Write-Host "Hello, World (from $env:COMPUTERNAME)"
```

Answer (score 4):

I think that not exposing PowerShell via SSH was one of the biggest design mistakes MS did. Even years later they are too proud / blind to do revert that poor decision.

I suggest you to not fight with WinRM and instead, use an SSH server on your Windows machine.
You'll benefit from having a simple, standard, secure way to connect to your server from any device (I'm doing remote PS sessions from my iPad).

There is the opensource cygwin and my favorite proprietary (with free offering) [PowershellServer](http://www.powershellserver.com/)

You'll thank me when your Windows server will play nicely with the rest of the world.

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE
I got back to this old thread and would like to add another option - using the new(ish) [AWS Systems Manager run-command](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/walkthrough-powershell.html) capability.
This allows you to have no administrative port exposed to the external world so no need to fiddle with host / cloud firewalls.
It also provide other benefits like auditing, permissions etc...

Comment: I'd agree this is much better solution as of today