# Copy files from one windows server to another in the release phase of VSTS

Tags: azure-devops

I have a use case where I need to copy some binaries from one windows server to another in a specified directory and then restart the IIS server. This will have below steps.

```
create backup of existing files in win server 1 -> stop IIS -> copy new files from win server 2 -> start IIS
```

The app is running on an ec2 instance.

Is there a way to automate this in the release phase of VSTS ? How can I achieve this if this is something not supported out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to copy some binaries from one windows server to another in a specified directory and then restart the IIS server.

You could use the task [Windows Machine File Copy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/windows-machine-file-copy?view=azure-devops) to copy those binaries from one windows server to another:

```
- task: WindowsMachineFileCopy@2
  inputs:
    sourcePath: 
    #machineNames: # Optional
    #adminUserName: # Optional
    #adminPassword: # Optional
    targetPath: 
    #cleanTargetBeforeCopy: false # Optional
    #copyFilesInParallel: true # Optional
    #additionalArguments: # Optional
```

Or you could create a share folder on the remote server, then we could just use the copy task those binaries:

[image]

To restart the IIS, just like the Krzysztof Madej said, you could use the PowerShell on Target Machines task to execute the powershell scripts to restart the IIS.

Answer (score 1):

It should be doable. What you should do is:

- enable PS remoting on ec2 instance to be able to stop and start iis. You can find this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21920773/execute-powershell-script-remotely-on-amazon-ec2-instance-from-my-local-computer) how to do this. On Azure DevOps you may use [PowerShell on Target Machines task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/powershell-on-target-machines?view=azure-devops)
- copy files from and into ec2 instance over scp. More details are [here](https://medium.com/@dearsikandarkhan/files-copying-between-aws-ec2-and-local-d07ed205eefa) and for that you can use [Copy Files Over SSH task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/copy-files-over-ssh?view=azure-devops)